# Having problems with AngularJS html5Mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, base-url, pretty-urls

I am currently having trouble with AngularJS html5Mode. I am working on a blog site that is hosted on my localhost WAMP server. I have a base URL defined in my index.html file and I have html5Mode set to true in the config section in my app.js file and I also have a .htaccess file in my directory.

This is what my url looks like without html5 mode enabled.
http://localhost/Blog/index.html/#posts

If I load my site like this:
localhost/Blog/
or
localhost/Blog/index.html it will redirct
to
localhost/Blog/posts which is what I want.

But if I try to type this url manually or refresh the page it goes to localhost/dashboard and If I click on one of the other links it will go to
localhost/nameOfLink

I am not 100% sure but I think the problem could be in the .htaccess file

This is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="blog" class="no-js" ng-cloak>
<head>
    <base href="/Blog/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#29B6F6">
    <meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#29B6F6">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#29B6F6">
    <title>Phone reviews</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/paper/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='primary-font-css'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:300,400,500,700' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav0">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="login.html" class="navbar-brand">Phone Reviews</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav0" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li ng-click="scroll()" ng-class="{ active: isActive('/posts')}"><a href="#/posts">Home</a></li>
                        <li ng-click="scroll()" ng-class="{ active: isActive('/contact')}"><a href="#/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li ng-click="scroll()" ng-class="{ active: isActive('/registration')}"><a href="#/registration">Register</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">My Account <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-init="userInit(<?php echo $_SESSION['name'] $_SESSION['role']; ?>)">
                                <li><a href="#">{{user}}</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Favourites</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li> 
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div> <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>

        <header class="header">
            <h1>Phone Reviews</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <h4>Success!</h4>
            <p>You have successfully registered! Go to your email to confirm account.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="social-icons">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 content"><div ng-view></div></div>
            <div ng-include="'includes/sidebar.html'"></div>
        </div>

        <div ng-include="'includes/footer.html'"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script async defer data-pin-hover="true" data-pin-tall="true" data-pin-round="true" data-pin-save="false" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
<script src="ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="page.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('blog', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'])

.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.
      when('/posts', { templateUrl: 'includes/main.html', controller: 'MainCtrl' }).
      when('/posts/:postUrl', { templateUrl: 'includes/post.html', controller: 'PostCtrl' }).
      when('/contact', { templateUrl: 'includes/contact.html', controller: 'ContactCtrl' }).
      when('/registration', { templateUrl: 'includes/register.html', controller: 'RegistrationCtrl'}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/posts'});
}]);
```

This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```